# What happens if onPause() or onStop() interrupt a function with nested callbacks from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, activity-lifecycle

I have a function which has nested callbacks (onDataChange() etc.) from the Firebase Database. What happens if app stops or pauses before all the callbacks get executed (for example the user receives a phone call before receiving the dataSnapshot from FirebaseDatabase)? Do the remaining callbacks get executed in the background or do they not get executed at all?

Here's my code:

```
        mUserOrder.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    mUserOrder.child(Integer.toString(lastOrders.get(n - 5))).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {     //getting the orderId of the order to be removed
                                                @Override
                                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                    removeOrderID = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                                                    mDatabaseOrder.child(removeOrderID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                        removeOrder = dataSnapshot.getValue(RequestOrder.class);
                                                        mRecycleOrdersDB.child(removeOrderID).setValue(removeOrder);
                                                        mDatabaseOrder.child(removeOrderID).removeValue();
                                                        mUserOrder.child(Integer.toString(lastOrders.get(n - 5))).removeValue();


                                                        progress.hide();
                                                        startMainActivity();
                                                        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The listeners will all execute until:

1. You remove the listeners.
2. The app process dies (which could happen at any time it's no longer visible to the user).
3. On newer versions of Android, the app cuts network access to the app because it's been in the background too long after becoming invisible. Upon regaining visibility, the listeners will begin to trigger again when the Firebase SDK regains connectivity.

It's customary to add listeners during onStart(), when the activity becomes visible, and remove them during onStop(), when the activity becomes invisible.

Comment: Ok. But will the remaining callbacks run if the app is paused or stopped? Would the remaining callbacks be able to make UI changes in case they do get executed? @doug

Comment: The callbacks will execute as I've outlined in my answer. UI updates are possible after an activity is paused or stopped, because the view hierarchy is still attached.  Updates invalid after an activity is destroyed, because the views are essentially gone and will never come back.  You should *never* hold on to references to views after onDestroy, or you may leak them.  You really need to remove your listeners before then.